# Can we extract the main object in streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `FootballTeam` class that contains `Footballer` class. Using streams is it possible to get the `FootballTeam` from a list of football teams if the `FootballTeam` contains a `Footballer` with a particular `id`. Is it possible to do the below with streams. i.e Get both the `targetFootballer` and `targetTeam`;

```
FootballTeam targetTeam = null;
Footballer targetFootballer = null;

for(FootballTeam team : list.getFootballTeams()){
    for(Footballer f : team.getFootballers()) {
        if(f.getId() == 1){
           targetFootballer = f;
           break;
        }
    }
    if(targetFootballer != null) {
        targetTeam = team;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking to retrieve the first `FootballTeam` and `Footballer` when the condition `if(f.getId()==1)` is met or the last one?

Comment: not possible since you cannot use a non final variable(targetFootballer) inside lambdas.

Comment: what if its final. and yes the condition is the one on the id

Comment: @user3310115 my question is do you want to stop the iteration as soon as the condition is met and then retrieve the `FootballTeam` and `Footballer`?

Comment: Yes exactly. That would be what should happen ideally.

Comment: I think you are missing a second `break` inside the `if` condition, correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don’t think in terms of loops, but rather what high-level operation you’re performing, e.g. finding the first element matching a criteria. The biggest obstacle for expressing such an operation, is that Java methods can not return two values. Using a `Map.Entry` as a pair type holding both results, you can use

```
Map.Entry<FootballTeam,Footballer> target = list.getFootballTeams()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(team -> team.getFootballers()
                     .stream()
                     .filter(f -> f.getId() == 1)
                     .map(f -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(team, f)))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```

Since you’re likely want to perform a subsequent operation on these values, you might avoid storing the result in a variable and apply the operation directly, e.g.

```
list.getFootballTeams()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(team -> team.getFootballers()
                     .stream()
                     .filter(f -> f.getId() == 1)
                     .map(f -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(team, f)))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(e -> {
        FootballTeam targetTeam = e.getKey();
        Footballer targetFootballer = e.getValue();
        // do your action
    });
```

Here, the action is only executed if a match has been found and you don’t need explicit code dealing with absent values. In the first example, `.orElse(null)` says that the `target` should be `null` if no match has been found, so you have to test for `null` later-on.